# What support does Isabelle have for relations represented by binary predicates?

Tags: isabelle

In an Isabelle formalization, I’m representing relations by binary predicates. I would like to have operators that perform typical relation operations like composition and inversion using this representation.

The document “What’s in Main” only mentions such operators for the representation by sets of pairs. The `Relation` theory says at the beginning, “Relations – as sets of pairs, and binary predicates”. However, I couldn’t find much support for the binary predicate representation in this theory. All I found were several lemmas with a mysterious `pred_set_conv` attribute.

Is there extensive support for relations represented by binary predicates? In particular, are there operators for common relation operations defined? Where are these things documented?

Comment: Why don't you just define your own composition and inversion (and other needed operations)? This seems easy enough. I know, this might be like reinventing the wheel (if a suitable relation theory/library for this already exists), but in this case the "wheel" seems to be a very simple wheel, and you gain independence from external libraries/theories.

Comment: Or do you need complicated lemmas or theorems about these operations that you would rather reuse from a library/theory instead of proving yourself?

Comment: I don’t want to use my own definitions, because this would make the code non-canonical and thus less easy to understand. I don’t consider independence from external theories to be very important; in fact, I typically consider reinventing the wheel to be worse. In this particular case, it’s even not depending on some third-party library but on the core library, which should be be fairly well-known, stable, and long-lasting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The support for relations as sets of pairs is slightly better developed than for binary predicates, but quite a lot is available. Many relation operations, however, are instances of more general operations on functions and predicates or they are indeed obtained using `pred_set_conv`. They may therefore be quite hard to find. Use the `find_theorems` command or panel to find the lemmas. Here is a brief summary of the usual operations:

- Composition: `relcompp` (infix `OO`)
- Inverse: `conversep` (notation `_\<inverse>\<inverse>`)
- (Reflexive) transitive closure: `tranclp` and `rtranclp`
- Intersection: `inf`
- Union: `sup`
- Inclusion: `op <=` (I find the lemmas `predicate2I` and `predicate2D` particularly useful)
- Graph of a function restricted to a domain: `BNF_Def.Grp`
- Inverse image under two functions: `BNF_Def.vimage2p`
- Well-foundedness and accessibility: `wfP` and `accp`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is already very useful. Could you maybe elaborate a bit on `pred_set_conv`? From searching the standard library source code, I understand that it is some core attribute of HOL that links inductive predicates and inductive sets. However, it isn’t documented in the Isabelle/Isar reference manual. What is this predicate about and where is it documented?

Comment: There are also problems with intersection and union. The `inf` and `sup` functions do not seem to work for binary predicates (those with types of the form `'a ⇒ 'b ⇒ bool`), only for unary ones. Isabelle complains that type `'b ⇒ bool` is not of sort `semilattice_inf`. Furthermore, Isabelle does not accept the notation `⊓` and `⊔` for `inf` and `sup` in my theories, although this notation is used in `HOL.Relation`. Why is this?

Comment: I corrected `\<converse>` to `\<inverse>`. However, already two peer reviewers rejected this correction. Reason? “This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post’s owner.” Needless to say that, judging from their profiles, these reviewers seem to have no clue about Isabelle. I guess they don’t even know that a `\<…>` is a representation of a symbol and that currently a symbol `\<converse>` just doesn’t exist.

Comment: Dear other reviewers, please first look into the Isabelle library source code, if you know how to find it, and realize that the notation for `conversep` uses `\<inverse>`, not `\<converse>`.

Comment: I was able to solve the problems with `inf` and `sup` more or less. The trouble with binary predicates occurs only after `value`. In lemma statements everything works fine. The notation `⊓` and `⊔` is available when importing `HOL-Library.Lattice_Syntax`. Strange still that in `HOL.Relation` this syntax is successfully used, although this theory does not import `HOL-Library.Lattice_Syntax`.

Comment: The notation for `conversep` was indeed wrong. It is indeed `\<inverse>\<inverse>`. I corrected it in the post.

Comment: The lattice notation `⊓` and `⊔` is disabled in `Main` to avoid polluting the syntax space as the square notation is used in different contexts for different purposes.

Comment: Relations as predicates indeed do not work well with evaluation using `value` because they are represented as code, not as data. But you can evaluate them pointwise.

Comment: I don't know of a good documentation for `pred_set_conv`. It was introduced a few years ago, when the `set` type was again separated from predicates `_ => bool`. The attribute `pred_set_conv` registers rewrite equations that link set-based constants to predicate-based ones. These equations are used by `inductive_set` and the attributes `to_set` and `to_pred` to convert theorems between the two worlds. As a normal user, you shoul hardly ever have to use them. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16604803/2161467 for an exception.

Comment: Thanks a lot for elaborating on these things.